# Do you have roadmap to migrating source code on typescript/flow?

Tags: typescript, webpack, flowtype

I'm new to webpack community, but I want to improve my knowledge of how it works "under the hood". I faced with problem when I don't understand where which type is using for and it's look like for new contributors it is very difficult as well + strictly typed code has less likelihood to fall into deoptimization. So my question is - Do you have any ideas/roadmap to migrating source code on TypeScript/Flow? May be create some JSDocs? Looks like migrating `tapable`, `enhanced-resolve` don't look as something difficult.

Comment: Hi, this isn't a general discussion forum. If you want to contact the webpack team, you'll need to find one of their support sites or forums. This site is only for programming questions.

Comment: Moved discussion to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9196